# How to extract a string or number within brackets in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, substring

I have a XML like that=

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<UserRecord xmlns="http://www.company.com/api/user/2015/08" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Code1>(MC)MyCompany United Kingdom</Code1>
  <Code2>(MC)United Kingdom</Code2>
  <Organization1>(90)R&amp;D</Organization1>
  <Organization2>(1905)R&amp;D</Organization2>
  <Organization3>(903)Roadmap Dev</Organization3>
</UserRecord>
```

I am trying to extract the data between () brackets and trying to get XML in this format=

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<UserRecord xmlns="http://www.company.com/api/user/2015/08" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Code1>MC</Code1>
  <Code2>MC</Code2>
  <Organization1>90</Organization1>
  <Organization2>1905</Organization2>
  <Organization3>903</Organization3>
</UserRecord>
```

I tried to use "substring-before(substring-after(" but I couldn't really get to bottom of this and got confused how to put correct syntax.

Can you help me?

Thank you

Comment: Please post your code here.

Answer (score 2):

If you use

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(*) and contains(., '(') and contains(., ')')]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., '('), ')')"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

to change the elements and

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

to copy the rest unchanged then you initial expression `substring-before(substring-after(` should do.

Comment: You are a star Martin Honnen. Thank you so much. Your answer is working but I couldn't upvote your answer because it says I don't have enough reputation to do that.